# sparkle effect in jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, animation, effect

I want to make sparkle effect like this flash animation http://www.fbcoviedo.org/

Do you have any resource or suggestion how can I do that?

Thanks
Samir

Comment: That is a flash animation mate.. It is not JQuery!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the slideshow animation, I can exactly tell you how to do it, but first you need to make your mind up if you want to do it with Flash, or Jquery. Let me know and I will hive you the guidelines.